# Integration over manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, differential-forms

S is subset of $\Bbb R^3 $ consisting of the union of

1) $z$ axis

2) the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1,z=0$

3) the points $(0,y,0)$ with $y \ge1 $

Let $A$ be the open set $\Bbb R^3-S$. Let $C_1, C_2, D_1, D_2,D_3$ be the oriented 1-manifolds in $A$ like in the picture. $F$ is a vector field in $A, curlF=0$ in $A$, and $$\int_{C_1}F\cdot T=3$$

$$\int_{C_2}F\cdot T=7$$

What can you say about $$\int_{D_i} F\cdot T$$?

Can someone please give a pedagogical answer for this?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that you can move around a curve inside of $ \mathbb{R}^3 - S $ ("homotope") and preserve the value of the line integral. Secondly, if you pinch a curve, then you can break it at the pinch into two curves and the line integral of the initial curve will be the sum of the line integrals of the two. And of course, reversing the orientation of the curve will negate the line integral. I hope you will understand why these are true.

So $D_3 $ is obviously zero, you can contract it down to a point. $ D_1 $ I can pinch right in the middle, and write it as a sum/difference of $ C_1 $ and $ C_2 $ (depending on how the orientations will match up). And similarly $D_2 $ is two copies of $ C_1 $, if you will pull it to the other side of the circle.

I hope this will help!

Comment: I do understand the first paragraph. But I just do not get the second one. Would you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: how do you know that $D_3$ is $0$

Comment: You can shrink the $D_3 $ all the way down to a point while remaining inside $ \mathbb{R}^3 - S $, and the line integral over a point is 0.This is essentially the fact that you can use stokes theorem to rewrite the line integral as an integral of the curl over the obvious bounding surface.

Comment: Do you make the assumption that $D_2$ is two times $C_2$ then? @user226970

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. Imagine grasping $ D_2 $ at the two points where it in the picture it crosses $ S$. Now pull those to the left side of the circle, and now bring them together and pinch them, breaking $ D_2 $ into two circles that go around the vertical axis.

Comment: The original question (and diagram) are from Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds* (p322) and (very similar) from Shifrin's *Multivariable Mathematics* (p411).